# EventStore Competing Consumer Ordering

Tags: event-sourcing, eventstoredb

I am in the process of scaling out an application horizontally, and have realised read model updates (external projection via event handler) will need to be handled on a competing consumer basis.

I initially assumed that I would need to ensure ordering, but this requirement is message dependent. In the case of shopping cart checkouts where i want to know totals, i can add totals regardless of the order - get the message, update the SQL database, and ACK the message.

I am now racking my brains to even think of a scenario/messages that would be anything but, however i know this is not the case. Some extra clarity and examples would be immensely useful.

My questions i need help with please are:

1. What type of messages would the ordering need to be important, and
   how would this be resolved using the messages as-is?
2. How would we know which event to resubscribe from when the processes
   join/leave I can see possible timing issues that could cause a
   subscription to be requested on a message that had just been
   processed by another process?
3. I see there is a `Pinned` consumer strategy for best efforts affinity of stream to subscriber, however this is not guaranteed. I could solve this making a specific stream single threaded processing only those messages in order - is it possible for a process to have multiple subscriptions to different streams?

[image: eventstore ordering]

Answer (score 2):

To use your example of a shopping cart, ordering would be potentially important for the following events:

- Add item
- Update item count
- Remove item

You might have sequences like A: 'Add item, remove item' or B: 'Add item, Update item count (to 2), Update item count (to 3)'. For A, if you process the remove before the add, obviously you're in trouble. For B, if you process two update item counts out of order, you'll end up with the wrong final count.

This is normally scaled out by using some kind of sharding scheme, where a subset of all aggregates are allocated to each shard. For Event Store, I believe this can be done by creating a user-defined projection using partitionBy to partition the stream into multiple streams (aka 'shards'). Then you need to allocate partitions/shards to processing nodes in a some way. Some technologies are built around this approach to horizontal scaling (Kafka and Kinesis spring to mind).

Comment: Thanks TomW, so by having a hash of the aggregate identity i can shard off aggregates across threads/processes, the same would apply for sagas (i can hash from the saga identity) and also projections (aka views) where i give each view an ID. Essentially we ensure that messages are then handled one at a time in a sequential fashion within that particular thread/process. I will google some algorhtihins for hashing and sharding, any you recommend in meantime?